# Obter a PK de uma tabela e Inserir Como FK em outra

Tags: php, mysql

tenho uma herança em meu trabalho e estou com dificuldades para fazer funcionar.
Exemplo das Tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pessoa (
  idpessoa INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipopessoa VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idpessoa)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS juridica (
  idjuridica INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cnpj VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  inscrestad VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  razaosocial VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  nomefantasia VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  pessoa_idpessoa INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (idjuridica),
  FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_idpessoa) REFERENCES pessoa (idpessoa)
);
```

Pois bem, essa é uma parte da herança que tenho, estou tentando cadastrar uma pessoa Jurídica, mas antes tenho que cadastrar a Pessoa. Estou utilizando o PHP (aprendendo agora) e o código está o seguinte para a inserção de uma pessoa jurídica.

Conexão com o banco:

```
function abrirBanco(){
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","apsbd1");
    if($connection->connect_error){
        die("Conexão com o banco falhou: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }
    return $connection;
}
```

INSERT de Pessoa e Pessoa Jurídica:

```
function inserirPJuridica(){
    $banco = abrirBanco();

    //Insere uma Pessoa;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pessoa (tipopessoa) VALUES ('Juridica')";
    $banco->query($sql);

    //Seleciona o ID da Pessoa;
    $sql = "SELECT idpessoa FROM pessoa ORDER BY idpessoa DESC LIMIT 1";
    $res_idpessoa = $banco->query($sql);

    //Insere a Conexão entre Pessoa e Jurídica;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO juridica (cnpj, inscrestad, razaosocial, nomefantasia, pessoa_idpessoa) VALUES ('{$_POST["cnpj"]}', '{$_POST["inscrestad"]}', '{$_POST["razaosocial"]}', '{$_POST["nomefantasia"]}', '$res_idpessoa'";
    $banco->query($sql);
```

A Pessoa eu consigo inserir no banco, porém quando vou inserir a Jurídica ele da um erro

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\apsbd1\inc\funcoes.php on line 302
```

A linha 302 é a linha do $res_idpessoa = $banco->query($sql);

Provavelmente o query não é uma string que pode ser usada em um INSERT, como eu faço para inserir então o idpessoa da tabela pessoa para o pessoa_idpessoa da tabela jurídica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer o seguinte depois de executar a query de select, para recuperar o campo que você deseja do select:

```
$res_idpessoa = $banco->query($sql);
$dados = $res_idpessoa->fetch_array();
```

e no insert:

```
//Insere a Conexão entre Pessoa e Jurídica;
$sql = "INSERT INTO juridica (cnpj, inscrestad, razaosocial, nomefantasia, pessoa_idpessoa) VALUES ('{$_POST["cnpj"]}', '{$_POST["inscrestad"]}', '{$_POST["razaosocial"]}', '{$_POST["nomefantasia"]}', '".$dados['idpessoa']."' ";
```

Comment: O Insert de Pessoa PK como FK na tabela Jurídica deu certo, porém, o mesmo não esta acontecendo com a tabela "contato" que tem os campos (pessoa_idpessoa e contato_idcontato), eu tenho que reescrever o SELECT de idpessoa, ou posso aproveitar para o próximo INSERT?

Comment: Você pode sim passar o $dados['idpessoa'] retornado dessa query para ser usado na contato, pois pelo que entendi seria a próxima query a ser realizada, se for isso mesmo.